# What becomes the search path of a .dll loaded with System.loadLibrary() in java?

Tags: java, c++, dll, java-native-interface, loadlibrary

I have a system where I have 1 .exe file, 4 .dll files and one jar file where the dependencies are as shown below:

**A.exe** -> *calls* -> **B.dll** -> *calls through JNI* -> **C.jar** -> *loads with System.loadLibrary("")* -> **D.dll** -> *calls* **E.dll**

Now, **B** through **E** is one module and all those files are in the same directory. **A.exe** is an application placed in a different directory which can use several of these modules.

My main problem is that when **D.dll** tries to load **E.dll** I get a '*Can't find dependent libraries' java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError*. If I am standing in the module directory and run **C.jar** manually there is no such error and **D.dll** manages to load **E.dll** just fine.

So, my main question here is: *AddDllDirectory(%moduleDir%)* is run in **A.exe**, but how far does it actually get 'inherited'? Does **C.jar** somehow remove the directory added by this function? Is there a way to expand the dll search path from java, before the *System.loadLibrary("")* call, such that the loaded .dll inherits this search path?

1. The java.library.path is set to the module directory when **B.dll** starts the JVM through JNI
2. I want to avoid having **A.exe** altering the PATH environment variable
3. No changes should be necessary in **D.dll** or **E.dll**

Thanks in advance for any answers

Comment: Why do you get a Java excpetion `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError` when your system library `D.dll` tries to load the system library `E.dll`. What's the wording of the exception message? Is it `D.dll: %1 is not a valid Win32 application` or `no D in java.library.path`?

Comment: This is the error message: `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: <moduleDir>\D.dll: Can't find dependent libraries`
What happens here is that in java when `System.loadLibrary("D.dll")` is executed, it fails because it cannot find **E.dll** which **D.dll** depends on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here a short explanation for the error which occur in your case.

Following is assumed

- Java calls `System.loadLibrary("D");` the class is in directory APP_DIR
- `D.dll` depends on `E.dll`, both in directory DLL_DIR

**case 1** `java.library.path` not specified

```
no D in java.library.path
```

**case 2** `-Djava.library.path=%DLL_DIR%`

```
D.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
```

Because Java checks for the presence of `D.dll` in `%DLL_DIR%` load the library (using Windows LoadLibrary functionality). Windows tries to find the dependent `E.dll` which is not found in the `PATH` and not in the current directory.

**case 3** `-Djava.library.path=%DLL_DIR%` and `set PATH=%DLL_DIR%;%PATH%`

```
System.loadLibrary("D"); will be successful
```

some additional links about this topic

- [MSDN "Dynamic-Link Library Search Order"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [MSDN AddDllDirectory function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/hh310513%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [MSDN SetDllDirectory function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [SetDllDirectory inheritance issue](http://www.pretentiousname.com/setdlldirectory_inheritance/index.html#probl)

Comment: After reading the following from your last link:
`SetDllDirectory("") also affects how child processes loads their DLLs.
Good news: It does not affect dynamic linking... 
Bad news: It affects implicit linking...`
does this mean that if `D.dll` loads `E.dll` using dynamic linking the `AddDllDirectory()` function called in `A.exe` is ignored, whereas if `D.dll` loads `E.dll` statically it is not?

Comment: @MartinRindarøy I can't prove it myself (have never called Java code from a library). But for me the break is at the point where you call the JVM as the library resolving works different here. So the child `D.dll` will not inherit the settings from `A.exe`. Maybe you could in the Java code change the current directory to the location of `C.jar`, then the `LoadLibrary` from Windows would find the `C.dll` as it's in the current directory. Best would be do create a small test case for that.